# Why i'm getting out of memory exception?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code in Form1 :

```
namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Magnifier20070401.MagnifierForm mf;
        ScreenCapture sc;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Ffmpeg ffmp;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            ffmp = new Ffmpeg();
            sc = new ScreenCapture();
            //bitmap = ScreenShotDemo.ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen(true);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void StartRecording_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //bitmap = ScreenShotDemo.ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen(true);
            //bitmap.Save(@"c:\ffmpeg\test.bmp");
            ffmp.Start("test.avi", 25);
            for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
            {
                //bitmap = ScreenShotDemo.ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen(true);
                bitmap = (Bitmap)sc.CaptureScreen();
                ffmp.PushFrame(bitmap);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(35);
            }
            ffmp.Close();
```

This is the code of the ffmpeg class i did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    class Ffmpeg
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream p;
        String pipename = "mytestpipe";
        byte[] b;
        //int i, j;
        System.Diagnostics.Process process;

        public Ffmpeg()
        {

        }

        public void Start(string FileName, int BitmapRate )
        {
            p = new NamedPipeServerStream(pipename, PipeDirection.Out, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
            b = new byte[1920 * 1080 * 3]; // some buffer for the r g and b of pixels of an image of size 720p 
            process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86\ffmpeg.exe";
            process.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\pipetest\pipetest\ffmpegx86";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgr0 -video_size 1920x1080 -i \\.\pipe\mytestpipe -map 0 -c:v libx264 -r " + BitmapRate + " " + FileName;
            process.Start();

            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            p.WaitForConnection();
        }

        public void PushFrame(Bitmap bmp)
        {

            int length;
            // Lock the bitmap's bits.
            //bmp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
            //Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1280, 720);
            System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
                bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
                bmp.PixelFormat);

            int absStride = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride);
            // Get the address of the first line.
            IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

            // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
            //length = 3 * bmp.Width * bmp.Height;
            length = absStride * bmpData.Height;
            byte[] rgbValues = new byte[length];

            //Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, length);
            int j = bmp.Height - 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < bmp.Height; i++)
            {
                IntPtr pointer = new IntPtr(bmpData.Scan0.ToInt32() + (bmpData.Stride * j));
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(pointer, rgbValues, absStride * (bmp.Height - i - 1), absStride);
                j--;
            }

            p.Write(rgbValues, 0, length);

            bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
            /*for (j = 0; j < 25 * 10; j++) // put about 10 seconds of frames ( assumes 25 frames per second)
            {

                // put some data as rgb.. (rgb24bpp = 3 bytes per pixel)
                for (i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (((i) % 3) == 0)
                        b[i] = (byte)(i + j);
                    else
                        b[i] = 0;
                }


                p.Write(b, 0, b.Length); // send this rgb data to the pipe (ffmpeg.exe will read it..)
            }*/
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            p.Close();
            //process.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the class of the ScreenShot where the exception of the memory came up.
Thep rogram worked and afte some seconds out of memory:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
namespace ScreenShotDemo
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides functions to capture the entire screen, or a particular window, and save it to a file.
    /// </summary>
    public class ScreenCapture
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of the entire desktop
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureScreen()
        {
            return CaptureWindow(User32.GetDesktopWindow());
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates an Image object containing a screen shot of a specific window
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">The handle to the window. (In windows forms, this is obtained by the Handle property)</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public Image CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
        {
            // get te hDC of the target window
            IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
            // get the size
            User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
            User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
            int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
            int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
            // create a device context we can copy to
            IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
            // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
            // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
            IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
            // select the bitmap object
            IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
            // bitblt over
            GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
            // restore selection
            GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
            // clean up 
            GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
            User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
            // get a .NET image object for it
            Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
            // free up the Bitmap object
            GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
            return img;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a screen shot of a specific window, and saves it to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle"></param>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <param name="format"></param>
        public void CaptureWindowToFile(IntPtr handle, string filename, ImageFormat format)
        {
            Image img = CaptureWindow(handle);
            img.Save(filename, format);
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Captures a screen shot of the entire desktop, and saves it to a file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="filename"></param>
        /// <param name="format"></param>
        public void CaptureScreenToFile(string filename, ImageFormat format)
        {
            Image img = CaptureScreen();
            img.Save(filename, format);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing Gdi32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class GDI32
        {

            public const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020; // BitBlt dwRop parameter
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool BitBlt(IntPtr hObject, int nXDest, int nYDest,
                int nWidth, int nHeight, IntPtr hObjectSource,
                int nXSrc, int nYSrc, int dwRop);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleBitmap(IntPtr hDC, int nWidth,
                int nHeight);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateCompatibleDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteDC(IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr SelectObject(IntPtr hDC, IntPtr hObject);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Helper class containing User32 API functions
        /// </summary>
        private class User32
        {
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct RECT
            {
                public int left;
                public int top;
                public int right;
                public int bottom;
            }
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetDesktopWindow();
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowDC(IntPtr hWnd);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr ReleaseDC(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hDC);
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref RECT rect);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is on this line from the ScreenCapture class:

```
Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
```

This code worked fine on my brother computer but now back to my home i try it and get this exception. Strange.

This is the full exception error message:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024882
  Message=Out of memory.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap, IntPtr hpalette)
       at System.Drawing.Image.FromHbitmap(IntPtr hbitmap)
       at ScreenShotDemo.ScreenCapture.CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle) in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\ScreenCapture.cs:line 49
       at ScreenShotDemo.ScreenCapture.CaptureScreen() in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\ScreenCapture.cs:line 18
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Form1.StartRecording_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Form1.cs:line 48
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176340/how-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-full-size-window-in-c-sharp?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256455/c-sharp-code-for-capturing-full-screenshot?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try releasing the DC references after creating the bitmap.

```
        // get a .NET image object for it
        Image img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);            
        // clean up 
        GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
        User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
```

**EDIT:**

I think you need to dispose of the bitmap when you're done. Try surrounding it with a `using`.

```
        ffmp.Start("test.avi", 25);
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            using(bitmap = (Bitmap)sc.CaptureScreen())
            {
                ffmp.PushFrame(bitmap);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(35);
            }
        }
        ffmp.Close();
```

Comment: Mathew it's not that tried you'r solution didn't work on 500. I just checked now without you'r code solution as it was before if i change in Form1 in the loop that create the screenshots from 500 to 100 it's working without any problems. What are the changes i have a problem physical problem with my ram memories ? memtest356 didn't find anything and the program worked with 500 on my brother pc. I have 6gb ram.

Comment: So for some reason with 500 it's not working but with 100 it doe's.

Comment: Make sure you call `bitmap.Dispose()` in your loop when you are done with the image. Otherwise you are creating 500 images all in memory the size of the screen. Which I don't think you have enough memory for.